# Call js function on dynamic variable

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is this:

```
validateStep(stepNumber) {
  const self = this;
  this.$v.registration_step${stepNumber}.touch()

  if (this.$v.registration_step${stepNumber}.$error) {
    this.$q.notify('Controleer aub de velden opnieuw');
    return;
  }
  self.$refs.stepper.next();
},
```

But this isn't working.
As you can see I want to call .touch() on a dynamic variable depending on what step the user is currently in (so it would become this.$v.registration_step1.touch() if the user is currently in step 1.

How would you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try accessing the key in another way:

```
this.$v[`registration_step${stepNumber}`].touch()
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to work. I get this:
`TypeError: this.$v.registration["".concat(...)].touch is not a function`  

  
note: I refactored the registration object so my code now is this:  

  
 `validateStep(stepNumber) {
      const self = this;
      const step = `step${stepNumber}`;
      console.log(step);
      this.$v.registration[`${step}`].touch();

      if (this.$v.registration[`${step}`].$error) {
        this.$q.notify('Controleer aub de velden opnieuw');
        return;
      }
      self.$refs.stepper.next();
    },`

Comment: nvm you solution works. problem was that I was calling .touch instead of .$touch which was not relevant to this issue. Accepted your answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
this.$v['registration_step' + stepNumber].touch()
```

Comment: Also it doesn't seem to work. It states that it can't call .touch of undifined.

I reworked to code to this:  
  
`    validateStep(stepNumber) {
      const self = this;
      const step = `step${stepNumber}`;
      console.log(this.$v.registration[step]);
      const currentStep = this.$v.registration[step];
      currentStep.touch();

      if (currentStep.$error) {
        this.$q.notify('Controleer aub de velden opnieuw');
        return;
      }
      self.$refs.stepper.next();
    },`

But still no luck.